# How to escape square brackets in the content of an HTML using slim syntax?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, templates, haml, slim-lang

I need to print following using slim syntax:

```
tr 
  td "[Send] Value"
```

or

```
tr 
  td [Send] Value
```

So square brackets are not visible (so interpreted somehow different): I get only `Value`

How to escape `--> [Send] <--` ?

## Update:

Some workaround:

```
tr
  th = "[Send] Value"
```

but it I hope there is a more "**clean**" way to escape square brackets, other than using ruby interpreter to escape them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brackets are being parsed as containing the attributes for the element. You could add a “dummy” set of [attribute wrapping brackets](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Attributes_wrapper):

```
td () [Send] Value
```

You could also nest the content on the next line, using the [pipe character to signify it’s plain text](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Text__):

```
td
  | [Send] Value
```

Both of these produce `<td>[Send] Value</td>` as output.

Comment: @static As far as I know there is no other way to escape the `[` character.

Comment: Same *hack* applies to the `/` character (e.g. `p /charge`)